# Insert borders underneath selected rows in reactable R

Tags: r, reactable

I am trying to put black borders beneath specific rows of a Reactable table in R. For instance, using the `cars` dataframe as an example, I would like to put a horizantal black line beneath the 2nd and 4th rows of the table generated with the code below:

```
library(reactable)
reactable(head(cars))
```

I would like the output to look like the one in the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `rowStyle` argument, as in:

```
library(reactable)
reactable(head(cars),
          rowStyle = function(index) {
            if (index %in% c(3, 5)) {
              list(`border-top` = "thin solid")
            }
          })
```